# Blinding Barrage: Do you need ammo for each target?

Tags: dnd-4e

I know for ranged attacks you need one piece of ammunition for each target, but blinding barrage is a close attack.  Do you need ammo or a thrown weapon for each target?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

For powers that use a ranged weapon you need one piece of ammo for *each* target. This text is from Close Attack (PHB 271):

> If you’re using a projectile weapon to make a close attack, you need one piece of ammunition for each target, and if you’re using thrown weapons, you need one for each target.

Note: if you're using thrown weapons, this should only matter at very early levels before magic weapons are acquired as a magic dagger will return after each attack, so you only need the one.